# Django signals for Comment notification

Tags: django, django-signals

I am working on django project and I have written a `post_save` signal to notify post author when commented. Now, I want to add a `post_save` signal to notify post author & comment user that a comment (reply) is made. How do I approach this? This is because there is a parent-child relationship on my comment model.

Below are my model and signal code. Can someone assist please? I am new on django and have just started learning django signals.

```py
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey('forum.Post',related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reply = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='replies', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=250, blank=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=Comment)
def user_comment_post(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        comment = instance
        post = comment.post
        #reply = comment.reply
        text_preview = comment.text[:90]
        sender = comment.user
        notify = Notification.objects.create(post=post, sender=sender, comment=comment, user=post.author, text_preview=text_preview, notification_type=2)
        notify.save()
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what exactly you want help with.

Answer (score 2):

From the model structure :

- A new `Comment` object to a `Post` would have `Comment.reply` field **as `None`**
- A reply (another `Comment` object) to an existing `Comment` object would have `Comment.reply` **not as `None`** .Would have a parent `Comment` object.

So, check in the signal instance if `comment.reply is None` or not.

- `if comment.reply is None` it is a new comment to a post >>> send notification to Post owner only
- `if comment.reply is not None` it is a new comment (reply) to an existing comment of a post >>> send notification to Post owner and Comment owner

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=Comment)
def user_comment_post(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        comment = instance
        post = comment.post
        text_preview = comment.text[:90]
        sender = comment.user
        notify_post_author = Notification.objects.create(post=post, sender=sender, comment=comment, user=post.author, text_preview=text_preview, notification_type=2)
        notify_post_author.save()

        if comment.reply is not None:
            notify_comment_owner = Notification.objects.create(post=post, sender=sender, comment=comment, user=comment.reply.user, text_preview=text_preview, notification_type=2)
            notify_comment_owner.save()
```

Comment: Thank you @AchuthVarghese.. I now understand  the relationship. I tried it and it worked.

Comment: @ECHO you may also need to check if the post owner and the comment owner is the same.. if it's same then there would be two notifications.

Answer (score 1):

You could check in the same post_save hook if the comment being saved is a reply by performing an EXISTS query accessing it's related manager:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Comment)
def user_comment_post(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created and entities.replies.exists():
        # your code here
```